# Pandas filter where current row string contains string from previous row in different column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['1', np.nan, '2', np.nan, np.nan, '3', '4', '7', np.nan], 'col2':[np.nan, '1,2', np.nan, '0,3', '0,3', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, '7,8']})
```

which looks like this:

```
  col1 col2
0    1  NaN
1  NaN  1,2
2    2  NaN
3  NaN  0,3
4  NaN  0,3
5    3  NaN
6    4  NaN
7    7  NaN
8  NaN  7,8
```

I'm trying to figure out how to create a single vectorized filter that will return rows whose `col2` value contain the `col1` value from the previous row. If either `col1` or `col2` is `NaN`, the row should not be considered. Thus, on this df, the result should be:

```
1  NaN  1,2
8  NaN  7,8
```

At first I considered shifting `col1` down by one and using something like `isin`:

```
 df[(df['col1'].shift(1).fillna('').isin(something in here)]
```

But then i realized that `isin` doesn't handle each row separately, i.e it checks if each row is in the same list. So now i'm convinced i should be using something along the lines of `df['col2'].str.contains(df['col2'])` but i'm not quite sure how to handle the shifting and what not.

Again the goal is to have a vectorized filter such that i can do this:

```
filtered_rows = df[(filter_here)]
```

I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['1', np.nan, '2', np.nan, np.nan, '3', '4', '7', np.nan], 'col2':[np.nan, '1,2', np.nan, '0,3', '0,3', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, '7,8']})
df['col1_shifted'] = df['col1'].shift(1)
mask = df.apply(
    lambda x: x.col1_shifted in str(x.col2).split(',')
    if x.col1_shifted
    else False, axis=1
)
filtered_rows = df[mask][['col1', 'col2']]

filtered_rows

  col1 col2
1  NaN  1,2
8  NaN  7,8
```